# Flatten Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, conversion, formatting

I have a document with some precise formatting, created in Word.  This doc was converted to PDF for distribution.  Now the original is lost, and reconverting to Word using a PDF to word add-on from Microsoft results in many text boxes in the new DOC file.  How can I 'flatten' this to remove the text boxes and retain most of the formatting in order to update the contents? Recreating the original formatting would take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

There are many free OCR services for PDF files (I can't recommend a specific one myself since I haven't used them, but https://www.google.se/search?q=pdf+ocr can help you). These services can probably recover the text portions of the document, which may or may not be helpful depending on what you mean by "some precise formatting".